# iPhone: What are the Alert Sound supported in Push Notification Payload?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented Push Notification and have been using Default sounds every time. I know that there are many other sounds as well that I can use but I don't know the names of all sounds that Apple support for Push Notification. Can someone please help me to get the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any sound you desire (and you have the rights to) - but you need to correctly encode the sound to work on the device (caf, aiff, wav). You must embed the sound as a resource within your project bundle, you cannot use "Any sound" on the device. Once embedded, you can reference it by filename in your payload for the sound.

Caveat - your sound must be under 30 seconds long and there is no mechanism to loop the sound)

[Apple Push Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if there are already Apple supported different sounds available?

Comment: Just the default SMS sound, nothing more. I encourage you to file a feature request http://bugreporter.apple.com/ to allow for more system sounds AND for users custom ringtones to be used. It is a terrible lack of a feature (And the more people that request the feature, the more it will be seen)

Answer (score 2):

You could put your own sound file , which you like to play.

**From apple documentation.**

> You can package the audio data in an
>   aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in
>   Xcode, add the sound file to your
>   project as a nonlocalized resource of
>   the application bundle.

See [more](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

[The sound has to be bundled with your app.](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/25464-push-notification-sounds.html)